# Why does this happens when downgrading the library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Why does this happens when downgrading the library

```
   ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
    pyppeteer 0.2.5 requires importlib-metadata<3.0.0,>=2.1.1; python_version < "3.8", but you have importlib-metadata 4.12.0 which is incompatible.
    pyppeteer 0.2.5 requires urllib3<2.0.0,>=1.25.8, but you have urllib3 1.24.3 which is incompatible.
    Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 attrs-22.1.0 black-22.1.0 click-8.1.3 importlib-metadata-4.12.0 pathspec-0.10.1 regex-2022.8.17 toml-0.10.2 typed-ast-1.5.4 typing-extensions-4.3.0 zipp-3.8.1
    WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/scrapers-XJakbnzz/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a conflict of package versions. To fix it, you'll need to follow these steps:

```
1)pip list
2)copy all of your packages
3)create a new file called requirements.txt
4)put all of your packages in there (without versions). The file should look like this:

autopep8
certifi
chardet
charset-normalizer
click
colorama
discord
Flask
itsdangerous
pip
praw

(except this has to be a list of your packages that you got while running pip list)

5)pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will tell pip to solve the version conflict.